# Double slit: how identical is identical?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, identical-particles

[It works even with C60 molecules...](https://www.nature.com/articles/44348)

The authors of the above article already wrote in the abstract: "Of particular interest is the fact that C60 is almost a classical body, because of its many excited internal degrees of freedom and their possible couplings to the environment. Such couplings are essential for the appearance of decoherence, suggesting that interference experiments with large molecules should facilitate detailed
studies of this process."

Let us assume that we do the experiment twice, once with 12C60 and once with 13C60. Or with electrons and positrons. Or stereoisomers. Or excites states. Or whatever *slightly* different particles. Then we combine the two interference patterns.

How far will this pattern diverge from the one where we used *only* 12C60, *only* electrons...Gradually? Can only identical particles interfere? (I'm thinking of the entropy paradox: mixing two vials with *slightly* different stuff gives kTln2 mixing entropy, no matter how slight the difference is).

Comment: ‘ (think of 12-C60 and 13-C60, or stereoisomeres, or any inner state that survives the double-slit unchanged) ’ How is this ‘which-way’ information?

Comment: The double slit experiment has been performed with molecules much larger than C60. According to Wikipedia the record currently stands at molecules with 2000 atoms each, which was achieved in 2019.

Comment: @my2cts: Not "as is", but it's firstmost a gedankenexperiment and you could turn it into one. Or fish the molecules out of the pattern and measure their mass - how are the patterns correlated after "splitting"?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Let me rephrase my comment. Molecular properties are _not_ ‘which-way’ information.

Comment: In general the EM field and the EM field of the particle are always interacting .... if the fields involve a double slit then per Feynman more probable paths in the EM field are present (i..e. interference).  If we do anything to the particle after the slits then we effectively have a new interaction of the EM field with the EM field of the particle ... and no interference.  Particles always have wave properties, slits just make these properties visible.

Comment: Sorry folks, I realized I asked the totally wrong question. Blame it on the flu :-) Edited.

Comment: In QM, identical means absolutely identical. It worked for C60 precisely because they were able to make sure the C60 going through each slit really was in the same internal state. If you shot one C60 molecule at one slit and a different one with a different isotope inside at the other, you would get no interference effects.

Comment: Particles in double slit diffraction interfere with _themselves_.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question seems perfectly clear to me and there is a good answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, as long as the scalar wave approximation is OK, the pattern depends only on the geometry of the slits and the momenta of the individual particles. You can mix particle types as much as you like as long as their momenta are the same.

The pattern may differ if there is some sort of interaction between the particle spin and the slit orientation (the scalar approximation fails).